# Controlsfx - Spreadsheetview reordering + context menu of header (rows + columns)

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I was not able to find how on Spreadsheetview set reordering of rows (whole row) or columns (whole column) in same way as it was in TableView.

I am sorry I dont have a piece of code, because that what I am looking for.

Plus I have another question. How can I get/set ContextMenu for spreadsheetview but not for classic content inside, but context menus of HEADERS (column, row) (see picture, I want to set different Context menu instead of anchor/pin column)?
I was not able to find those informations.

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why do you means by "reordering"? You cannot drag and drop some columns to modify their order in the SpreadsheetView.

I'm afraid that no API has been designed in order to modify the ContextMenu of the columns and row headers.. But we can fix that in an ulterior version. Please consider posting in ControlsFX google group if you want faster answers : http://groups.controlsfx.org/

Comment: Yes I wanted drag and drop some columns as it was possible in classic TableView, but I found out it is not possible even in excel so I let it be.

Comment: TableView has been made to represent the view of a Database Table. Therefore, a column representing a data type can be drag n drop elsewhere. In a spreadsheet where one column may have different types and some cell spanning, it's impossible to drag n drop columns..